# Restful codeigniter limitation with files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I use PhilSturgeon RestFul libraries (Client and Server). 
I want to download a file from my client, it works with a lot of files, but when the file is big (>= 6 Mo), I get a blank page with no error.

Can I handle big files with this system ? My code si simply :

```
$data = file_get_contents('my_big_file.bmp');

$this->response(base64_encode($data), 200);
```

I didn't find any configuration dealing with timeouts or execution times in both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The problem you will face is that your servers RAM will get to it's max quickly if the file is too big and probably if the file takes a lot of processing time the script will time out. This has to do with your php.ini settings.

To fix this open your php.ini and change "max_execution_time" to the seconds you want. 0 is unlimited but that isn't good on a production level so set a time you think it will take.  If you want to be able to process files bigger than 128MB change the "memory_limit" to something higher.

It is also possible to set these via your php script/controller with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php e.g.

`ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); //Sets the memory_limit on 256MB
ini_set('max_execution_time', '900'); //Sets the max_execution_time to 900 seconds (15 minutes)`

Comment: My PHP config is already set to 10000 for max_execution_time, and 512M for memory. But I have always this problem.

Comment: Could you try putting `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` in the script and see if it returns any errors?

Comment: Nothing ! Always blank page... I put this code in client and server to test.

Comment: What value is your php.ini max_input_time on?

Comment: Could you try to set the value to -1. (This means unlimited) If the file is big the uploading process can take ages.